# How to retrieve values from table where joining key is not in joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have four tables as below:

```
users(
user_id PRIMARY KEY,
user_name, 
and-other-fields)

venues(
venue_id PRIMARY KEY,
venue_name,
and-other-fields)

user_venues(
user_venue_id PRIMARY KEY,
user_id FOREIGN KEY REF users,
venue_id FOREIGN KEY REF venues,
and-other-fields)

venue_quotes(
user_venue_id PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REF user_venues,
quote TEXT,
and-other-fields)
```

There are users in users table and venues in venues table. The user requests a venue to celebrate some event there specifying budget, time, date, duration which are termed as "and-other-fields" in venues table. And the venues responses the users through venue_quotes table.

Let say user_venues table has some data like below :

```
(1,1,1,...)
(2,1,2,...)
(3,1,3,...)
(4,2,1,...)
```

And say venue_quotes table has some data like below :

```
(1, "You are welcome!")
(2, "We are sorry!")
```

My Question is how can i retrieve all the fields from venues, users, user_venues, venue_quotes with the condition WHERE user_venues.user_venue_id NOT IN venue_quotes.user_venue_id .

I have tried the following Code but It returns me 0 Rows. So sad.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_venues
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = user_venues.user_id
INNER JOIN venues ON venues.venue_id = user_venues.venue_id
LEFT JOIN venue_quotes ON venue_quotes.user_venue_id = user_venues.user_venue_id
WHERE venue_quotes.user_venue_id NOT IN (user_venues.user_venue_id)
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

Please Help,
Thank you.

Comment: what you want to get ?

Comment: I want all the fields of `user_venues` table but only from those rows where `values that user_venue_id from user_venues table contains should not be in user_venues_id from venue_quotes table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the join as a left join (as you have) and then check for NULL in the WHERE clause

Something like this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM user_venues
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = user_venues.user_id
INNER JOIN venues ON venues.venue_id = user_venues.venue_id
LEFT JOIN venue_quotes ON venue_quotes.user_venue_id = user_venues.user_venue_id
WHERE venue_quotes.user_venue_id IS NULL
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you need to join the tables if you are selecting from `user_venues` . and checking in table `venue_quotes`

try this

```
   SELECT *
  FROM user_venues
  LEFT JOIN venue_quotes ON venue_quotes.user_venue_id = user_venues.user_venue_id
  WHERE venue_quotes.user_venue_id NOT IN (SELECT user_venue_id FROM user_venues)
  LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `WHERE venue_quotes.user_venue_id NOT IN (SELECT user_venue_id FROM user_venues)`

Comment: sorry to say but it returns the same result. Where I could not understand what my own code means is `LEFT JOIN venue_quotes ON venue_quotes.user_venue_id = user_venues.user_venue_id
WHERE venue_quotes.user_venue_id NOT IN (user_venues.user_venue_id)`. Is this valid statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM  venue_quotes
LEFT JOIN user_venues ON venue_quotes.user_venue_id = user_venues.user_venue_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = user_venues.user_id
INNER JOIN venues ON venues.venue_id = user_venues.venue_id

WHERE venue_quotes.user_venue_id NOT IN (SELECT user_venue_id FROM user_venues)
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```